# How many elements do the rings $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt3]/(\sqrt3)$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt3]/(1+\sqrt3)$ have respectively?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have solution but  I am not sure in it.

First) there are 3 elements ([0],[1], [2])

Second) 2 elements ([0],[1])

Comment: Seems right to me

Answer (score 2):

Both of your answers are correct. Here's how you can justify them.

First, note that the map
\begin{align*}
\Bbb Z[x]/(x^2 - 3)&\to \Bbb Z[\sqrt{3}]\\
x\mapsto\sqrt{3}
\end{align*}
is an isomorphism. Therefore,
$$
\Bbb Z[\sqrt{3}]/(\sqrt{3})\cong\left(\Bbb Z[x]/(x^2 - 3)\right)/(x)\cong\Bbb Z[x]/(x^2 - 3, x)\cong\Bbb Z[0]/(0^2 - 3) = \Bbb Z/(3).
$$

For the second ring, you can try a similar strategy. In this case,
\begin{align*}
\Bbb Z[\sqrt{3}]/(1 + \sqrt{3}) &\cong \left(\Bbb Z[x]/(x^2 - 3)\right)/(1 + x)\\
&\cong \Bbb Z[x]/(x^2 - 3, 1 + x)\\
&\cong \Bbb Z[-1]/((-1)^2 - 3)\\
&=\Bbb Z/(-2)\\
&=\Bbb Z/(2).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

It looks right, since

> $$\Bbb Z[\sqrt 3]/(\sqrt 3)\cong\Bbb Z[x]/(x,x^2-3)\cong\Bbb Z[x]/(x,3)\cong\Bbb Z_3$$$$\Bbb Z[\sqrt 3]/(1+\sqrt 3)\cong\Bbb Z[x]/(x,x^2-2x-2)\cong\Bbb Z[x]/(x,2)\cong\Bbb Z_2$$ Where $x^2-3$ is the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt 3$, and similarly $x^2-2x-2$ is the minimal polynomial of $1+\sqrt 3$.